# What happens in Kafka if you create a new partition for a topic?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-topic

I read on some guides online that if you are using key ordering the new partition will eventually break that ordering, I really can't see how.
Is this really what happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is what is *usually* happening. To be more precise, **there is no guarantee that the old ordering stays the same**.

The partitioning of messages is basically happening through

```
hash(key) % number_of_partitions
```

Let us assume you have a topic with two partitions. Your data (key:value) looks like this

```
a:1
b:1
c:1
a:2
b:2
c:2
```

Now, those messages would go into two partitions:

```
partition0: a:1, b:1, a:2, b:2
partition1: c:1, c:2
```

If you now add one partition and you produce new messages `a:3, b:3, c:3` into the topic you could end up like this:

```
partition0: a:1, b:1, a:2, b:2, a:3
partition1: c:1, c:2, c:3
partition2: b:3
```

Now, consuming the messages from this topic, you could end up processing `b:3` before processing `b:2` because the one consumer reading `partition0` might take longer then another consumer of the same ConsumerGroup reading `partition2`.

Comment: Ok, I thought Kafka used a different and and maybe more advanced approach than hashing to assign same keys messages to the same partition, thanks a lot.

Comment: You could always write your own custom partitioner class to define your own logic for a Producer.